# How to mitigate "[DEPRECATION NOTICE] registry v2 schema1 support will be removed in an upcoming release" in quay.io?

Tags: quay.io

[DEPRECATION NOTICE] registry v2 schema1 support will be removed in an upcoming release. Please contact admins of the quay.io registry NOW to avoid future disruption

This issue occurs if a `docker pull` is issued or the API is consulted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do anything; this warning is a mistake. See https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/39736